# I need to connect my form to a database (I think)

Tags: php, mysql, database, ftp

I have a conenct.php file that has $server, $user, $pass, $db

It seems like its trying to connect to a sql server.$conn

They also provided FTP information for me. (I'm not sure how I have to use this)

The instructions are to create a website from an illustrator file they created (which I have no problem doing). Then I have to collect name and email information and send it through. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the connect.php and FTP information to do that. Also, wouldn't the name/email have to be called something specific? I know this post might be a bit confusing. Let me know if I can clear anything up for you.
Thanks for the help!

Basically, I'm not sure I know what to do with the files they sent. I think I probably have to do a form action to the connect.php?

I checked in the FTP. All there is is a robots.txt and a .htaccess file

Comment: Uploading stuff is usually done using a FTP client like Filezilla. Enter the FTP information in there and connect

Comment: @pekka Yes, I have an FTP client, I don't have an issue uploading. My issue is connecting my form to the SQL server. I'm a front end designer, so I haven't really had to deal much with this. I'm not sure what they need me to do with the files provided.

Comment: This sounds like you need to build an entire form, and connect it to a database. That's a bigger job and can't be done with a couple of lines of code.

Comment: I know how to build a form and process it. I just don't know how to connect it to the database... @Pekka웃

Comment: This takes some learning and isn't something that can be answered well in a Stack Overflow question. There are tutorials out there for that. E.g. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Answer (score 0):

This can help get you started as to what to do with those connect.php variables. However, if you're just beginning PHP/MySQL dev, you'll have a bit more than this one page to read: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php